# Pip installation error on torch install inside virtualenv on RPi4

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, pytorch

I tried installing pytorch using pip inside a python3.7 virtual environment on my Raspberry Pi:

```
(env_hal) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -m pip install "torch==1.9.0" 
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.9.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0
```

The index pip looks in seems to be the default one. Why is it not listing torch?

---

Edit:
If I omit the version from the command, it unsuccessfully attempts to install this ominous torch package, which doesnt seem to be pytorch:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./audio/env_hal/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch) (5.4.1)
WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'torch' candidate (version 0.1.2.post2 at https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz#sha256=a43e37f8f927c5b18f80cd163daaf6a1920edafcab5102e02e3e14bb97d9c874 (from https://pypi.org/simple/torch/))
Reason for being yanked: 0.1.2 is past it's support date and confuses users on unsupported platforms
Building wheels for collected packages: torch
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pi/audio/env_hal/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-6h6ghes1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
    File "/home/pi/audio/env_hal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/pi/audio/env_hal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pi/audio/env_hal/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch
    Running setup.py install for torch: started
    Running setup.py install for torch: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/pi/audio/env_hal/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-15hetl4d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/audio/env_hal/include/site/python3.7/torch
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "/home/pi/audio/env_hal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pi/audio/env_hal/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u4qh01at/torch_77171faa079e464a8ea88699d6c51f7e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-15hetl4d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/audio/env_hal/include/site/python3.7/torch Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What does happen if you do: `python3 -m pip install "torch`, without setting the version.

Comment: Could you try `python3 -m pip install torch==1.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`?

Comment: @Ivan this yields the same error message as the one that I posted

Comment: @czr see edit above, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 uninstall torch` first to clean up install/uninstall leftover, and run `pip3 install torch` again.